# Foreach loop within an array in laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach

I am using lava charts and i need to loop some data into a chart.
This is what each loop needs to look like.

```
->addRow([$date, $value1, $value2]);
```

This is what i have already tried , but i seem to get an error. :

```
->addRow([   
foreach($data as $row){    
echo $row->date;
echo $row->value1;
echo $row->value2;
}   
]);
```

But i get an error, as i cannot use the foreach loop in an Array.
How do i get these loop values into an array ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($data as $row){    
    $whatever->addRow([$row->date, $row->value1, $row->value2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($data as $row){ 
    someObj->addRow([$row->date, $row->value1, $row->value2]);
}
```